# python-pptx: How do a enter the title text on a "Section and Header" slide

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm using the pptx module to create a PowerPoint "Section Header" slide, where I then enter the section title.

```
import pptx
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation()

mySectionHeaderSlide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[2])
mySectionHeaderSlide.shapes.title.text = "This is my section header
title."

prs.save('SectionHeaderDemo.pptx')
```

When I do this, my section header title is in the region I'd consider the subtitle box of the Section Header slide, not the title box.  That is, the bottom box of the two boxes, not the top box.

How do I get my section header title to be in the top box of the Section Header slide?

My apologies for any typos in my code examples. For corporate reasons, I can't access StackOverflow on the same system I do my Python programming, so I can't cut-and-paste.

Comment: That's part of the Master for the slide in question. Your choices are 1) programmatically use the other text shape. 2) Alter the slide master to fundamentally fix the problem.

Comment: Ah.  It seems that in python-pptx's "Section Header" slide, the section heading title text and section heading subtitle text are reversed from what I expected, with the title on the bottom and the subtitle on the top.  I expected the reverse.  Given that, I'll work with how python-pptx defines things.

Comment: So you're using the built in .pptx as your template file? You could make your own, even if it were just the built-in one modified. (In my code I allow a user-selectable "template" presentation.)